# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined - doesn't read array from props

Tags: reactjs

Have two components : 
StyledService - parent of all ServiceItem components
ServiceItem - child, component which has heading and list of elements

ServiceItem:

```
const ServiceItem = ({ heading, items }) => (
    <StyledWrapper>
        <StyledHeader>{heading}</StyledHeader>
        <StyledList>
            {items.map(item => (
                <StyledItem key={item}>{item}</StyledItem>
            ))}
        </StyledList>
    </StyledWrapper>
);
```

ServiceSection:

```
const ServiceSection = () => {
    const [services] = useState([
        { heading: 'Development', items: ['Mobile development', 'Web development'] },
        { heading: 'Business', items: ['Marketing', 'SEO'] },
        { heading: 'Design', items: ['UX Design', 'Branding'] },
    ]);

    return (
        <StyledWrapper>
            {services.map(({ heading, items }) => (
                <ServiceItem key={heading} heading={heading} items={items} />
            ))}
        </StyledWrapper>
    );
};
```

When I run this browser alert me with that :
Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.
The problem is that 'items' props in the ServiceItem component doesn't read 'items' as array but it is array, so I don't know where is the problem. 'items' props is the 'items' array put in the service variable in ServiceSection component. 
Can't resolve this trouble for one hour. Thanks.

Browser:

```
ServiceItem
src/components/atoms/ServiceItem/ServiceItem.js:36
  33 | const ServiceItem = ({ heading, items }) => (
  34 |     <StyledWrapper>
  35 |         <StyledHeader>{heading}</StyledHeader>
> 36 |         <StyledList>
  37 |             {items.map(item => (
  38 |                 <StyledItem key={item}>{item}</StyledItem>
  39 |             ))}
```

Comment: before you used map try to console the items is that array

Comment: Try to comment lines `<StyledList>{items.map(item => (<StyledItem key={item}>{item}</StyledItem>))} </StyledList>` in ServiceItem.js so that you have no errors in your application and then inspect React components hierarchies in the Chrome Developer Tools ("⚛️Components" tab). You'll be able to see if `items` in `<ServiceSection>` are passed further.

Comment: I try repeat you code in playground and it works, maybe it's help you: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-playground-2pujq

Comment: Yes it also works for me, I don't see a problem.